# How to specify the decimal separator in Google Charts?

Tags: google-visualization, decimal, separator, decimal-point

Is there a way to specify the decimal separator in Google Charts?

By default it seems to be based on the locale, however the need I have is to have the decimal separator to be a "dot" rather than the comma for some locales (my users are in a locale where comma as decimal separator is the default, but considered old-fashioned/obsolete)

This would be for all numbers, from axis labels to tooltips. The rest of the locale options would be unchanged.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe, loading the lib with the correct location help some one (worked for me):

```
// Load Google Charts for the Portuguese locale.
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'], 'language': 'pt'});
```

More on: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#loadwithlocale

Comment: Playing with language could give you another problem - for example dates that includes month names will be translated to Portuguese as well so this solution is not very good.

Answer (score 5):

Google Visualization API provides [formatters](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters) that can be used to reformat data in a visualization

According to [NumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat):

> Describes how numeric columns should be formatted. Formatting options
>   include specifying a prefix symbol (such as a dollar sign) or the
>   punctuation to use as a thousands marker.

The below example demonstrates how to apply formatter to `Salary` column in order to render its value using `.` symbol (`decimalSymbol`  and  `groupingSymbol` properties of [NumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters) object are used for that purpose)

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["table"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
    data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time');
    data.addRows(5);
    data.setCell(0, 0, 'John');
    data.setCell(0, 1, 10000);
    data.setCell(0, 2, true);
    data.setCell(1, 0, 'Mary');
    data.setCell(1, 1, 25000);
    data.setCell(1, 2, true);
    data.setCell(2, 0, 'Steve');
    data.setCell(2, 1, 8000);
    data.setCell(2, 2, false);
    data.setCell(3, 0, 'Ellen');
    data.setCell(3, 1, 20000);
    data.setCell(3, 2, true);
    data.setCell(4, 0, 'Mike');
    data.setCell(4, 1, 12000);
    data.setCell(4, 2, false);

    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ prefix: '$',decimalSymbol: '.', groupingSymbol: '.' });
    formatter.format(data, 1); // Apply formatter to second column

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1]);

    
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(view, { width: '420px', height: '240px' });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

**Update**

According to [Customizing Axes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes) you can control the formatting of label numbers with `hAxis.format` and `vAxis.format`

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
    data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time');
    data.addRows(5);
    data.setCell(0, 0, 'John');
    data.setCell(0, 1, 0.1000);
    data.setCell(0, 2, true);
    data.setCell(1, 0, 'Mary');
    data.setCell(1, 1, 0.2500);
    data.setCell(1, 2, true);
    data.setCell(2, 0, 'Steve');
    data.setCell(2, 1, 0.800);
    data.setCell(2, 2, false);
    data.setCell(3, 0, 'Ellen');
    data.setCell(3, 1, 0.2000);
    data.setCell(3, 2, true);
    data.setCell(4, 0, 'Mike');
    data.setCell(4, 1, 0.1200);
    data.setCell(4, 2, false);

    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ prefix: '$', decimalSymbol: '.', groupingSymbol: '.' });
    formatter.format(data, 1); // Apply formatter to second column

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1]);


    var table = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(view, { width: '420px', height: '240px', vAxis: { format:'$#,##0.00'  }  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: Does not work for axis labels (http://jsbin.com/xaxekusilu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: You can control the formatting of label numbers with `hAxis.format`, for example:  `vAxis: { format:'$#,##0.00'  }` (see the updated answer for a more details)

Comment: Yes, already using a custom format, but this does not affect the decimal separator, even with a '0.0' format it comes out as '0,0'

Answer (score 0):

If your data comes from a controller with model, you can just use *model.data.replace(",",".")*. So google chart can show your float data.